# in list VS in tuple condition in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, conditional-statements

I want to know what are the best practices between using the `in tuple` and the `in list` conditions and know why, as the following scenario:

```
my_variable = 'A'
if my_variable in [2, 'A', None]:
    return True
elif my_variable in (2, 'A', None):
    return True
```

And if possible list the advantages/disadvantages of tuples/lists in this case.

Comment: a `set` would be the most efficient here... `my_variable in set((2, 'A', None))`. (but is that really worth it? see comment below...)

Comment: That's a pretty pointless optimisation, in my opinion. Such tiny sets/lists/tuples are constructed, searched and destroyed very quickly, so choosing the fastest is not worth it

Comment: @ForceBru Yes because containers never contain more than 3 elements ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands actually in my case, the containers could be very large, just didn't mention it in the example.

Comment: @getName I think you missed my sarcastic tone ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` and `tuple` both have an O(n) time complexity for `x in container` checks.

However, `set` have an O(1) for this check (most of the time, the worst case scenario will have a worse time complexity due to hash collisions).

See these timings for a list, tuple and a set with 1 million elements:

```
from timeit import Timer

li = list (range(1, 1000000))
t =  tuple(range(1, 1000000))
s =  set  (range(1, 1000000))

def x_in_list():
    999999 in li

def x_in_tuple():
    999999 in t

def x_in_set():
    999999 in s

print(min(Timer(x_in_list).repeat(5, 5)))
print(min(Timer(x_in_tuple).repeat(5, 5)))
print(min(Timer(x_in_set).repeat(5, 5)))
```

Outputs

```
0.08769642199999961
0.09637485699999981
9.329999999252436e-07
```

Comment: `set`s are *average* case O(1) (hash collusions mean it could be worse). Also only worth building a `set` if you're doing to do *multiple* `in` tests (I'm sure you know this, but worth spelling it out)

Comment: @Chris_Rands we always talk about average case when talking time complexity (for example quicksort is always considered as O(nlogn) even though its worst case is O(n^2)), but I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in runtime is negligible between List, Tuple, and Set if there are only 3 elements.

Pep8 style guide doesn't say anything about this as far as I know, so you can use whichever you prefer.

Something the other answers missed, as far as readability goes, is you can declare a set directly like this:

```
if my_variable in {2, 'A', None}:
    print(True)
```

Comment: *Technically there is a difference with using Set over List or Tuple - objects are compared with hash rather than equality, defined in a class as \_\_hash\_\_ rather than \_\_eq\_\_

Answer (score -1):

A `tuple` is an immutable sequence, whereas a `list` is a mutable sequence, which means tuples can't be changes, but list can be.

If you don't want to modify the data structure you are checking `in`, use `tuple`, else use list, otherwise both behave the same.

```
my_variable = 'A'

if my_variable in [2, 'A', None]:
    print(True)
if my_variable in (2, 'A', None):
    print(True)
```

The output will be

```
True
True
```

Note that both list and tuple have `O(n)` time complexity to check, to get an average `O(1)` complexity, use a set.

```
if my_variable in set([2, 'A', None]):
    print(True)
#True
```